# How to set LogFileDirectory in Intellitrace plan.xml file for windows service

Tags: debugging, intellitrace

Can someone show me an Intellitrace plan.xml file that has a  set properly? I'm trying to follow the directions for running Intellitrace against a service. I can't get the service to start with Intellitrace. The error is 0x80004005 which makes sense because I can see that its trying to create the log file in the directory where the service lives. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find a single plan.xml file that has LogFileDirectory set to anything other than blank.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

`<LogFileDirectory useDefault="false">D:\YourDirecotry</LogFileDirectory>`